# Use prepared statement or dynamic command in Postgresql stored procedure?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I am learning Postgreslq and I have a question about this code sample:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CreateProject(
IN projectName VARCHAR(45),
IN projectYear SMALLINT)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
--     PREPARE addProject (VARCHAR(45),SMALLINT) AS
--     INSERT INTO projects (projectName, year) VALUES ($1, $2);
--     EXECUTE addProject(projectName, projectYear );

    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO projects (projectName, year) VALUES ($1, $2)'
    USING projectName,projectYear;
END $$;
```

I am trying to write stored procedure that would be safe against SQL injection. Coming from Mysql, I know that I would have to use prepared statement with parameters. Here in Postgresql it doesn't allow to(commented code), on the other hand if I use dynamic command it works. Could someone explain, why it is not possible to use prepared statement in such a situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execution plans are prepared and cached for PL/PgSQL, it happens automatically. So, there's no need to use `PREPARE` inside PL/PGSQL ( As you've seen, you can't) for the sake of optimisation.

SQL injection is possible if you use dynamic arguments and use concatenation to append them instead of parameterising. However, since you are running a simple insert without dynamic columns/tables, `EXECUTE` is not needed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure CreateProject(
   IN projectName  VARCHAR(45),
   IN projectYear  SMALLINT  )
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO projects (projectName, year) VALUES ($1, $2);
END $$;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=51b54e0f6d1c76fa961357fca59ab7b0)